# Can't use Geckodriver in Selenium on Mac

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I'm attempting to use Selenium with Python on a Mac.

```
from selenium import webdriver  
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I get these errors:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

I've tried a number of different solutions, including altering my $PATH to add the location geckodriver is installed ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)), and placing the geckodriver executable file in usr/local/bin, per the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) on Pypi.python.org for my version of Selenium (3.0.2).

$PATH now includes the path to where geckodriver is, but I continue to get the above errors. Any ideas?

I'm running Python 3.5.

Comment: Have you reloaded your bash session after adding the location of geckodriver to your path? Can you share what is displayed when you `echo $PATH`

Comment: This is what is displayed: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` . Also reloaded my terminal session.

Comment: And what happens if you try to run `geckodriver` from the terminal? You should see something like this if it finds it `1483412667814 geckodriver INFO Listening on 127.0.0.1:4444`

Comment: Here's what I got: `1483414605939 geckodriver INFO Listening on 127.0.0.1:4444`

Comment: Hmm, not sure then. It should be able to find it if you can run it from the terminal. Try adding the `executable_path` option `webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/path/to/your/geckodriver")`

Comment: @LucasTierney that worked. Wish there was some way around it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132211/discussion-between-friendlyman23-and-lucas-tierney).

Comment: I had the same problem trying to 'build' from within SublimeText and the comment from @LucasTierney above ( `webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/path/to/your/geckodriver")` ) fixed it for me. Thanks! Maybe this could be answer and we could upvote?

Comment: @drstevok it was an answer but got converted to a comment